# How to avoid clone when destructuring tuple?

Tags: rust, clone

I have the following code:

```
let (_, expression) = arg.clone();
match expression.node {
    ExprLit(_) => (),
     _ => arguments.push(arg),
}
```

which clones `arg` (expression is of type [P](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ptr/struct.P.html)<[Expr](http://manishearth.github.io/rust-internals-docs/syntax/ast/struct.Expr.html)>).

But, we do not need to clone `arg`.

I tried to avoid cloning this variable and I came up with this solution:

```
{
    let (_, ref expression) = arg;
    if let ExprLit(_) = expression.node {
        return;
    }
}
arguments.push(arg);
```

but I do not like it (extra curly brackets and use of `return`).

Is there another solution in this specific case?

Comment: Cloning has a nonzero but finite (and sometimes quite small) cost. Therefore it is trivially irrational to avoid it "at all cost", since that includes many contortions where the avoidance has a higher cost than the cloning.

Comment: Describing the cost of cloning as finite is a bit misleading, since it can be arbitrarily large, e.g. cloning a `Vec<T>` is `O(length)`, cloning an `Expr` requires duplicating the whole AST contained in it (which can be arbitrarily large) etc. That said, `clone`ing generally isn't too bad, especially if it's not inside a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the elements of a tuple as if they were numbered struct fields (starting from zero), i.e. without pattern matching, which avoids the need to clone or create a new scope.

```
if let ExprLit(_) = arg.1.node { ... }
```